# Model summary in Flux.jl

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I am trying to understand the model I have created with `Flux.jl` along with the specific parameters it has. Is there a built in function which will show me this info? I know that `Flux.params(model)` will show me some of this but that result is not human readable. I also tried just `display(model)` and it shows me the layers but not the parameters. I would want something like  [PyTorches Summary function](https://github.com/sksq96/pytorch-summary).

Comment: There is a PR https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/pull/1467 although unlike the linked pytorch summary function, it does not track output sizes.

Comment: That PR looks great!